# ASP.Net Core OData - filter by number of nested matching

Tags: sql, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, odata

I have a root `Company` entity with `CompanyType` children. I want to filter companies that have all provided types. It's possible to create such filter in pure SQL

```
SELECT Companies.Id, Companies.Name
FROM Companies
JOIN (
  SELECT CompanyTypes.CompanyId FROM CompanyTypes
  WHERE CompanyTypes.CompanyTypeId IN (123, 456, 789, 555)
  GROUP BY CompanyId
  HAVING COUNT(*) = 4
) Types ON Companies.ID = Types.CompanyID
```

It's also possible to create such filter using linq to sql

```
var typeIds = new[] { 123, 456, 789, 555 };
var companies = await EFContext.Companies.Where(company => company.CompanyTypes.Count(type => typeIds.Contains(type.CompanyTypeId)) == typeIds.Length).ToListAsync();
```

Is there a way to compose such query using odata syntax? I've tried this

```
companyTypeIds/any(i: i eq 123) and companyTypeIds/any(i: i eq 456) and companyTypeIds/any(i: i eq 789) and companyTypeIds/any(i: i eq 555)
```

It gives expected result but underlying query is different and it becomes very slow when number of conditions grows. Is there a way to make it more efficient like provided SQL queries? The backend is using ASP.Net Core 6, EF Core 6, ASP.Net Core OData 8 (latest at the moment).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having the SQL and the LINQ that you want to translate into an OData query makes this a much easier proposition, the `WHERE IN ()` combined with `HAVING COUNT(*) = 4` can both be implemented in OData v4.01 and recently that support has been improved

> **[Adding support for $count segment in $filter collections in OData WebAPI](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/odata/adding-support-for-count-segment-in-filter-collections-in-odata-webapi/)**
> In OData core  v7.9.0 we added improved support for $count segment in $filter collection properties.
>
> ```
> $filter=navProp/$count($filter=prop gt 1) gt 2
> $filter=collectionProp/$count($filter=prop gt 1) gt 2
> ```

For this LINQ:

```
var typeIds = new[] { 123, 456, 789, 555 };
var companies = await EFContext.Companies.Where(company => 
company.CompanyTypes.Count(type => typeIds.Contains(type.CompanyTypeId)) == 
typeIds.Length).ToListAsync();
```

The following should work for your query:

`~/Companies?$filter=CompanyTypes/$count($filter=CompanyTypeId in (123, 456, 789, 555) eq 4)`

Comment: Thanks! It works if `CompanyTypes` is a collection of objects. But if I have `CompanyTypeIds` collection of numbers is it possible to filter by collection value itself rather than by nested property, something like `$filter=companyTypeIds/$count($filter=this in (1,2,3)) eq 3`?

Comment: Yeah that TBH that did confuse me, I assumed it to be a spelling mistake, next time please post the relevant fragment from the `$metadata` document, especially in this case. The syntax i have posted works if the property represents a navigation to a collection.  In my experience this type of syntax will NOT work on an array, but I do not have an API that has an array property like that to test it on. One of the compromises with OData is that we try not to expose data through arrays, we try to keep everything queryable. I'll try to construct a demo to prove this.

Comment: tell me if this works, if it does I'll update my answer: `$filter=companyTypeIds/$count($filter=$it in (123, 456, 789, 555)) eq 4` $it is the literal value used to refer to the current item in the expression

Comment: It seems not. I'm getting "The parameter '$it' is not in scope." error.

Comment: Yeah thought so. By using an array you are specifically preventing the use of these advanced query filtering conventions. The problem is usually at the LINQ to SQL side when you do this, the way you convert the related list into an array makes it hard to resolve the expected query. Bottom line is you should avoid arrays if you want to perform any but the simplest of operations against their contents

Comment: TBH having an array here instead of exposing the navigation property is bizarre and explicitly creates a _reverse leaky abstraction_, your API is assuming too much about the implementation, and in this case it blocks the client, you made it TOO simple. If the caller wanted an array, they would constrain the results with a `$select=CompanyTypeId`, you can even make that they default `$expansion` if you want to, but you gain nothing by disabling the client with a structure like that.